# Vigenere cipher in python

Tags: python, encryption, vigenere

Writing a vigenere cipher in python and I've got completely lost in it, anyone fancy giving me a hand and suggesting things that could be improved/make it work correctly? Currently I'm getting all sorts of errors

```
letters='ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'
print ("This program will take a keyword, and use it to encrypt plaintext.")
def keyword():
    print ("Please enter your keyword")
    keyword = input()
    return keyword

def plaintext():
    print ("Please enter your plaintext")
    plaintext = input()
    return plaintext

def translate (keyword, plaintext):
    keywordtwo=0
    number=0
    keyword=keyword.upper()
    length = len(plaintext)
    lengthtwo=len(keyword)
    for symbol in plaintext:
        number=letters.find(symbol.upper())
        if number!=-1:
            number+=letters.find
        num%=len(letters)
        if symbol.isupper():
            translated.append(letters[number])
        elif symbol.islower():
            translated.append(letters[number].lower())
        if keywordtwo==len(keyword):
           keywordtwo=0
    else:
        translated.append(symbol)
    return ' '.join(translated)




keyword = keyword()
plaintext = plaintext()
translated = translate(keyword, plaintext)

print ("Your new text is:")
print (translate(keyword, plaintext))
```

Comment: What sort of errors do you get?

Comment: TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +=: 'int' and 'builtin_function_or_method' is the most recent one @PieterWitvoet

Comment: number+=letters.find doesn't seem correct, you have to pass an argument to find

Comment: It might also be worth reading up on some literature to improve your coding style. Your program is messy and difficult to understand for the reader. This is an extremely important skill to master and is best learned sooner rather than later.

Answer (score 2):

`TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +=: 'int' and 'builtin_function_or_method'` refers to the code at line 22: `number+=letters.find`.

`number` is an int (number) and `letters.find` is a method (a built-in method), and you're trying to add those together. That's not going to work. What you probably intended to do was to call that function, which looks like `number += letters.find(...)`, where ... stands for whatever letter you want to look up.

The next error you'll get will be something like `UnboundLocalError: local variable 'num' referenced before assignment`. That's on line 23: `number%=len(letters)`. `num` does not exist, I assume you meant `number` instead.

Then you'll get `NameError: global name 'translated' is not defined`, which refers to line 31: `translated.append(symbol)`. You're trying to add an item to a list named `translated`, but `translated` does not exist at that point (you do define it further down, outside your `translate` function, but even then, you should use a local variable, not a global one). Add `translated = []` to the start of your `translate` function.